# Delet an outputTable with a actionButton Shiny R

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying show the TableOuput first, according to the user inputs, there are: "media" and "desv_pad". When I click on the button "rodar", the table is showed. After that, I need to delete the output Table "saida" when a press the actionButton "reset", then my interface will be clean to receive new inputs and run again, but my code isn't working.

```
    library(shiny)


ui <- fluidPage(
  
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel("Inputs",
                 numericInput(inputId = "media", 
                              label = "Mean:",
                              value = 0,
                              min = 0),
                 numericInput(inputId = "desv_pad", 
                              label = "Standard Deviation:",
                              value = 1,
                              min = 0),
                 numericInput(inputId = "delta", 
                              label = "Mean Shift:",
                              value = 0.5,
                              min = 0,
                              max = 2,
                              step = 0.25),
                 numericInput(inputId = "n", 
                              label = "Size of Samples:",
                              value =  5,
                              min = 0,
                              max = 10,
                              step = 1),
                 numericInput(inputId = "alfa", 
                              label = "% alpha",
                              value = 0.27,
                              min = 0,
                              step = 0.1),
                 numericInput(inputId = "beta", 
                              label = "% beta:",
                              value = 97,
                              min = 0,
                              step = 0.1),
                 numericInput(inputId = "xb_teo", 
                              label = "%X max:",
                              value = 10,
                              min = 0),
                 actionButton("rodar", "Run")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      
      
      tags$h4( tableOutput('saida')),
      tags$br(),
      tags$br(),
      tags$br(),
      tags$br(),
      tags$br(),
      
      
      tags$br(),
      actionButton("reset", "Reset")
      
      
    )
  )
)  


server <- function(input, output) 
{
  v <- reactiveValues(data = NULL)
 
   observeEvent(input$rodar,{   
               output$saida <- renderTable({ #resultado,
                   
                   
                   passo_n <- 0 
                   #Recebendo os inputs:     
                   n <-input$n
                   Xb_teo <- input$xb_teo# input Xbarra percentual teorico definido pelo usuario
                   med<- input$media #input da media
                   desv_pad <- input$desv_pad #input do desvio padrao
                   alfa <- input$alfa #% determinado pelo usuario
                   beta <- input$beta #% determinado pelo usuario
                   delta <- input$delta
                   
                   v$data <- c(n, Xb_teo,med, desv_pad, alfa, beta, delta)

                 })
               })
  
                observeEvent(input$reset, {
                  v$data <- NULL

                })
                
                output$saida <- renderTable({
                  if(is.null(v$data)) return()
                  v$data
                  
                })

}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Is there any message output - What do you mean by code isn't working?

Answer (score 0):

There are lot of undefined variables in your code. I have replaced them with constants for now.

Put `output$saida` outside `observeEvent`. Try this app :

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel("Inputs",
                 numericInput(inputId = "media", 
                              label = "Mean:",
                              value = 0,
                              min = 0),
                 numericInput(inputId = "desv_pad", 
                              label = "Standard Deviation:",
                              value = 1,
                              min = 0),
                 numericInput(inputId = "delta", 
                              label = "Mean Shift:",
                              value = 0.5,
                              min = 0,
                              max = 2,
                              step = 0.25),
                 numericInput(inputId = "n", 
                              label = "Size of Samples:",
                              value =  5,
                              min = 0,
                              max = 10,
                              step = 1),
                 numericInput(inputId = "alfa", 
                              label = "% alpha",
                              value = 0.27,
                              min = 0,
                              step = 0.1),
                 numericInput(inputId = "beta", 
                              label = "% beta:",
                              value = 97,
                              min = 0,
                              step = 0.1),
                 numericInput(inputId = "xb_teo", 
                              label = "%X max:",
                              value = 10,
                              min = 0),
                 actionButton("rodar", "Run")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      
      
      tags$h4( tableOutput('saida')),
      tags$br(),
      tags$br(),
      tags$br(),
      tags$br(),
      tags$br(),
      
      
      tags$br(),
      actionButton("reset", "Reset")
      
      
    )
  )
)  


server <- function(input, output) 
{
  v <- reactiveValues(data = NULL)
  
  observeEvent(input$rodar,{   
      passo_n <- 0 
      #Recebendo os inputs:     
      n <-input$n
      Xb_teo <- input$xb_teo# input Xbarra percentual teorico definido pelo usuario
      med<- input$media #input da media
      desv_pad <- input$desv_pad #input do desvio padrao
      alfa <- input$alfa #% determinado pelo usuario
      beta <- input$beta #% determinado pelo usuario
      delta <- input$delta
      
      v$data <- c(n, Xb_teo,med, desv_pad, alfa, beta, delta)
      
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$reset, {
    v$data <- NULL
    
  })
  
  output$saida <- renderTable({
    v$data
  })
  
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: I corrected the post (now it's complete the code that I was trying), but it's working yet.